# How to automatically convert a LaTeX math-mode equation into Python / numpy code?

Tags: python, math, migration, latex, symbolic-math

Mathpix can automatically convert scanned formulas into LaTeX math code.

Is there a similar tool that automatically converts scanned formulas or LaTeX math-mode equations (code) into python (numpy) code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there's nothing that's really comprehensive. However, there is [this tool](https://github.com/augustt198/latex2sympy), called latex2sympy, that converts (some) LaTeX equations to SymPy. It's SymPy, not numpy (so will give you, e.g., x**2 and not np.square(x), but might help. Here's a screenshot of its README info showing some basic usage. It's not going to handle anything complicated or unusual, but for basic equations it might do the trick.

[latex2sympyREADME](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0O11K.png)

Comment: thanks, I'm familiar with symbolic math in python using sympy. wasn't necessarily needing every math function to be in numpy and really was more interested in non-numpy math operations like `x**2` like you said

Comment: it says `latex2sympy` uses ANTLR to install, but never used or heard of that before

Comment: I'm facing issues about how to install it. I installed "antlr4-python3-runtime", but library is not importing after installation. @K Allison, can you pls elaborate how to integrate this on a project?

Comment: @MinhajulIslam once import is successful, you should be able to just run it with a LaTeX expression to return the SymPy expression e.g. `print(process_sympy("e^{(45 + 2)}"))` returns e**(2 + 45). Check that you have the Antlr tool (antlr-4.7.1-complete.jar file) set up in Java correctly. @develarist yeah it's a bit of a hassle to set up. There's some documentation here https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/getting-started.md - involves both a tool set up in Java and a Python package.

Comment: @KAllison, Thank you. I installed altlr-4.9 and it works fine. Integration is weird, It costs a lot of time!!